# Angular Okta-SignIn-Widget - observe event or hook when Allowed into an application or not

Tags: javascript, angular, okta-api, okta-signin-widget

Right now, everything is working great - just need to be able to subscribe, or find an event or hook so I can log a successful login vs:

[image: user is not assigned to the client application]

Now these both come back from Okta as a success because the user is Authenticated, but not necessarily a user with access to said application. We have users that can be part of one or many applications, my question is:

How do I hook into the widget to whether or not a user has logged in successfully, and is there a way to tell if this error pops up (ie not allowed to use said Okta application)?